# Join in OPEN JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, openjpa

Call me stupid but this thing has been eating away my productive time like crazy. So simplified question,

```
There are four tables with 3 m-n relationships 
A m-n B   <LinkTable AB>
B m-n C   <Link Table BC>
C m-n D   <Link Table CD>
```

I want the join and get all A.ids. What is the join syntax in openJPA?

Or if that is too complex just give me all the inventories of a customer having order less than 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open JPA Join syntax follows JPA, there is no such difference if you stick to JPA.

So if A and B are to be joined on a column say `id` then mapping will be

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="ID")
```

Comment: Well I use eclipselink to generate the entity files and mappings automatically. That part is done. What I am confused about is queries involving joins of a large sets of tables.

Comment: you mean query that would be generated as per your mapping defined ?